# Bash Script sed -e

Tags: regex, linux, bash

```
count_items=`curl -u username:password -L "websitelink" | sed -e 's/<\/title>/<\/title>\n/g' | sed -n -e 's/.*<title>\(.*\)<\/title>.*/\1/p' | wc -l`
```

Above I have a Bash script that extracts the titles from an XML file, but how do I change the regex so that it extracts a title name from a div tag?

Example: extract title out of: `<div id="example""><a href="">title</a></div>`

I know it's silly to be done via Bash but I have no choice, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you think about replacing your <title> things by <div id="example""><a href="">title</a></div> and see if it works ?

Comment: no because there are many titles, i dont know what the title name will be, it needs to dynamically collect title names :(

Comment: You need to give us a hint as to how you're going to differentiate "title" DIV's from other ones. Are all the titles in links, i.e. `href`s? Will your `href`s always be contained on a single line?

Comment: Does "I have no choice" mean "homework"?

Comment: Homework about curl command line arguments? What kind of class would it be though? CURL 101 maybe :)

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) instead of trying to parse XML with a regex.

Comment: im not parsing xml im extracting, and i have to use bash for this. any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Extracting requires parsing, and xmlstarlet is a command-line tool.

Comment: yeah but it isn't installed to a linux machine by default is it, i need to use a simple bash script that doesnt need anything to be installed

Answer (score 2):

Parsing XML without a parser is ugly; the SO crowd always strongly recommends against it, and people always insist on doing it anyway. Usually the brute-force, special-case solutions kludged together with the wrong tools fail beyond a certain level of complexity, and then those people are back where they started. You have been warned! ;)

You mention elsewhere that you need to be able to do this on a "plain Linux machine with nothing installed." While you may not find specialized XML parsing tools on every Linux box, these days it's hard to find one that doesn't have Perl installed. Or at least awk. When you hit the limits of what you can do with regular expressions in sed, I recommend going with either awk or perl for a clean, flexible and legible solution. Use of Perl with a "real" Perl XML library would be optimal but in a pinch you can still get a lot done with "out of the box" Perl.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the single-line example given:

```
echo '<div id="example""><a href="">title</a></div>' | sed -E -n 's/(.*<div.*<a href="">)([^<]*)(<.*<\/div>.*)/\2/p'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using nothing but Bash:

```
$ string='<div id="example""><a href="">title</a></div>'
$ pattern='.*>([^<]+)<.*'
$ [[ $string =~ $pattern ]]
$ target=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
$ echo $target
title
```

There are lots of ways for this to fail. Here's one:

```
$ string='<div id="example""><a href="">title</a>this text will be grabbed instead</div>'
```

You can keep trying to make the regex more robust:

```
pattern='.*>([^<]+)</a.*'
```

but it's an uphill battle. Use a proper parser.